# Webpack not compiling files on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, npm, webpack

I want to use Webpack to compile files for my Django app on Heroku, and am using `webpack-bundle-tracker` to keep track of the modules created in `webpack-stats.json`. When I run webpack locally, it compiles all the files and bundles them into the output directory, no problem. But when I run webpack on Heroku, it shows me that all the chunks were emitted, but none of the files appear in the output directory. When I check the content of `webpack-stats.json` it always says `"status" : "compiling"`.

Here's the content of my `webpack.config.js`.

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker')

module.exports = {
        context: __dirname,

        entry: './assets/js/index',

        output: {
                path: path.resolve('./assets/bundles/'),
                filename: '[name].js',
        },

        plugins: [
                new BundleTracker({filename: './webpack-stats.json'}),
        ],

        module: {
                loaders: [
                  { test: /\.jsx?$/,
                        exclude: /node_modules/,
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        query: {
                                presets: ['react']
                        }
                  }
                ]
        },

        resolve: {
                modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', 'bower_components'],
                extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
        },
}
```

I want webpack to bundle my assets the same way on heroku as it does on my local machine. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: It would make more sense to use a CI tool like [travis](https://travis-ci.org/) to build your js and push the result to heroku when you deploy.

Comment: @agconti that makes sense. Thanks!